# Sql Subquery Not working "ORA-00904: "A2"."ID_USER": invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to run this query in Oracle

```
SELECT A1.ID_USER,A1.CNAME,
 (SELECT CNAME 
   FROM
   (SELECT CNAME,COUNTER
    FROM
      (SELECT id_Category AS IDCATEGORT,COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
        FROM gamescateg
        WHERE id_game IN
       (SELECT ID_GAME
        FROM UserGames
        WHERE id_user=UsersGamers.ID_USER
        )
       GROUP BY id_Category
       )
    JOIN Categories 
    ON id_Category =IDCATEGORT
    ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
   )
  WHERE rownum = 1
 ) AS FAVORITECATEGORY
FROM UsersGamers A1
JOIN UsersGamers A2 ON A1.ID_USER= A2.ID_USER
```

but i get the the error

```
ORA-00904: "A2"."ID_USER": invalid identifier
```

A2.ID_USER need for do the subquery 
why ?
how to solve that?
could you help me?

**I SOLVE IT BY CREATE FUNCTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FAVORITECATEGORYfunc( idnumber NUMBER )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_conc_names VARCHAR2(32676); 
BEGIN
  SELECT CNAME INTO l_conc_names 
   FROM
   (SELECT CNAME,COUNTER
    FROM
      (SELECT id_Category AS IDCATEGORT,COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
        FROM gamescateg
        WHERE id_game IN
       (SELECT ID_GAME
        FROM UserGames
        WHERE id_user=idnumber
        )
       GROUP BY id_Category
       )
    JOIN Categories 
    ON id_Category =IDCATEGORT
    ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
   )
  WHERE rownum = 1;
  RETURN l_conc_names;
END;
```

and the query was

```
select CNAME,FAVORITECATEGORYfunc(id_user) from usersgamers
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: You join `UsersGamers` to itself using the same column `ID_USER`, why?

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you are trying to do.  I suspect the query is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've expanded your query to make it more readable and commented the problem (invalid identifier). There's a reference to alias A2 where A2 can't be.

```
select A1.ID_USER, A1.CNAME,
(
    SELECT CNAME FROM 
    (
        SELECT CNAME, COUNTER 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT id_Category AS IDCATEGORT, 
            COUNT(*) AS COUNTER 
            FROM gamescateg 
            WHERE id_game IN 
            (
                SELECT ID_GAME FROM UserGames
                WHERE id_user=A2.ID_USER    /* your problem is here */
            ) 
            GROUP BY id_Category 
        )
        JOIN Categories 
        ON id_Category =IDCATEGORT
        ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
    )
    WHERE rownum = 1
) AS FAVORITECATEGORY
FROM UsersGamers A1 
JOIN UsersGamers A2
ON A1.ID_USER= A2.ID_USER
```

Have you considered rewriting this to avoid so many nested queries? Instead of wrapping them one inside the other, try structuring it around the favourite category using joins instead.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a superficial fix will not fix the query.  So, please explain what you are trying to do.  I suspect the query is much more complicated than it needs to be.  And, it is very hard to decipher.

Your problem is, superficially, that you are using the table name rather than the alias.  So, one would think that writing the query like this would fix the problem:

```
SELECT A1.ID_USER, A1.CNAME,
       (SELECT CNAME 
        FROM (SELECT CNAME, COUNTER
              FROM (SELECT id_Category AS IDCATEGORT, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
                    FROM gamescateg
                    WHERE id_game IN (SELECT ug.ID_GAME
                                      FROM UserGames ug
                                      WHERE ug.id_user = UsersGamers.ID_USER
                                     )
                   GROUP BY id_Category
                  ) cc JOIN
                  Categories c
                  ON c.id_Category = cc.IDCATEGORT
             ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
            )
        WHERE rownum = 1
       ) AS FAVORITECATEGORY
FROM UsersGamers A1 JOIN
     UsersGamers A2
     ON A1.ID_USER = A2.ID_USER;
```

But, alas, it will not.  Oracle limits the scoping depth for correlated subqueries.  So, this doesn't fix the problem; you'll just get another error.

The most reasonable thing that such a query might be doing is getting the most common category for a given user.  If so:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT ugr.ID_USER, ugr.CNAME, c.cname, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ugr.ID_USER, ugr.CNAME
                                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM UsersGamers ugr JOIN
           UserGames ug 
           ON ugr.ID_USER = ug.ID_USER JOIN
           Categories c
           ON c.id_Category = ug.id_Category
      GROUP BY ugr.ID_USER, ugr.CNAME
     ) u
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like this and make sure you are getting desired result.

```
SELECT A1.ID_USER,
       A1.CNAME,
      (SELECT CNAME
           FROM
             (SELECT CNAME,
                     COUNTER
              FROM
                (SELECT id_Category AS IDCATEGORT,
                        COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
                 FROM gamescateg
                 WHERE id_game IN
                     (SELECT ID_GAME
                      FROM UserGames
                      WHERE id_user=UsersGamers.ID_USER --replaced A2 with UsersGamers
                      )
                 GROUP BY id_Category
                )
              JOIN Categories ON id_Category =IDCATEGORT
              ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
             )
           WHERE rownum = 1
        ) AS FAVORITECATEGORY
FROM UsersGamers A1
JOIN UsersGamers A2 ON A1.ID_USER= A2.ID_USER
```